# How to call a function on onClick, defining it from string literals

Tags: javascript, function, string-literals, template-literals

So basically, I have created a button using string literals and added an onClick method to call a function, but when I click on that button it throws an error as shown below:

```
localstorage.html:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: deleteUser is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (localstorage.html:1:1)
```

Below is the code that I have written:

```
  function showNewUserOnScreen(user) {
    let parentNode = document.getElementById("listOfUser");
    let childhtml = `<li> ${user.username} - ${user.email}
                            <button onclick="deleteUser('${user.email}')"> Delete </button>
                    </li>`;

    parentNode.innerHTML = parentNode.innerHTML + childhtml;
  }
```

And now the function is:

```
  function deleteUser(emailId) {
    console.log(`deleteUser function called`);
//     localStorage.removeItem(emailId);
  }
```

The connection to both the function:

```
  function showNewUserOnScreen(user) {
    let parentNode = document.getElementById("listOfUser");
    let childhtml = `<li> ${user.username} - ${user.email}
                            <button onclick="deleteUser('${user.email}')"> Delete </button>
                    </li>`;

    parentNode.innerHTML = parentNode.innerHTML + childhtml;
  }

  function deleteUser(emailId) {
    console.log(`deleteUser function called`);
//     localStorage.removeItem(emailId);
  }
```

Comment: Please read [ask] and provide a [mcve] (preferably using the stack snippets feature of the question editor to provide a live demo). We can't see how those fragments of code are connected to each other. The problem is likely to do with the scope that `deleteUser` is declared in, but that's a guess. The dependency of intrinsic event attributes on globals is just one of the features that make them awful and why you should use `addEventListener` instead.

Comment: NB: While rare, email addresses *can* contain `"` and `'` characters which would break your code since you don't appear to be applying any form of escaping.

Comment: @Quentin, I have edited the question, both the function are in the same scope

Comment: `deleteUser` doesn't need to be in the same scope as `showNewUserOnScreen`, it needs to be in the same scope as `onclick` (i.e. global … as I said in my last comment).

Comment: Unable to reproduce the problem When I run your last block of code with an array of test data if works as expected, i.e., the generated buttons call the delete method. So what what is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

One problem in your code is that you use single quotes instead of backticks inside your deleteUser call.

But the main problem is that you create functionality as a string literal, and that is bad practice.

I recommend creating your elements with `document.createElement`, and using `addEventListener` to make a button interactive.

Here is an example that uses a string (user = "henk") to demonstrate a solution

```
 function showNewUserOnScreen(user) {
   let parentNode = document.getElementById("listOfUser");
   let btn = document.createElement("button")
   btn.innerText = `Delete ${user}`
   
   parentNode.appendChild(btn)
   btn.addEventListener("click", () => deleteUser(user))
 }

 function deleteUser(user) {
   console.log(`deleteUser ${user}`);
 }
 
 showNewUserOnScreen("henk")
```

Comment: @Kokodoko, I understand this but still if I want to create a button using string literals and call the function as I did, How can it be done??

Comment: If I paste your code on JSFiddle it just seems to work? See https://jsfiddle.net/b1h02e65/1/